# Get Screenr video thumb image url

Tags: youtube

In youtube you can get the url of the thumb image by using the video id.
For example :

for the video : http://www.youtube.com/embed/J6bGnSEwdKY

the id for the video is J6bGnSEwdKY

so you will find the img at http://img.youtube.com/vi/J6bGnSEwdKY/1.jpg

I want to  have the same url for a screenr casts (http://www.screenr.com)

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it screenr provide an API :

http://www.screenr.com/api/oembed.json?url=http://www.screenr.com/oXs